# Storing HTML in SQL and accessing it throgh Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am storing small webpages in html format in a varchar(max) column in MS SQL server 2008. Now I want the gridview to show the column as a button/hyperlink such that when I click it, I will be redirected to a new webpage which will render the html in the table corresponding to that row.

I tried using the buttonfield control but there doesn't seem to be any way I can access the datafield and underlying html in that case. Any ideas, peeps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link to point to `somepage.aspx?id=xxx`, where xxx is id of the row that contains the required html. In `somepage.aspx` in `Page_Load` event read teh html from sql server and write it to the client.
Something like this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="mypage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID") %>">View</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: But then, how do I get the id to which I have to bind? I have an ID column in sql, but I don't want to show it on the gridview. Is there a way I can use that Id column without binding it to sql?

Comment: You do not have to show it in the grid, you just have to generate the link using this column

Comment: using eval()? or is there another way to do this?

Comment: yea.. this could work, i'll try it. Doesn't eval() slow down the page though?

Comment: it works, thanks :)
though I have a feeling it is a dirty way of doing it. Let me know if you come across some other way too.. cheers

Comment: This is not a dirty way of doing this.  This is the standard way of implementing this scenario.